# Can't show image from asset in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm starting to learn flutter and I'm, at the moment, trying to show an image from a file, but it's not showing it and I don't know why. I changed my `pubspec.yaml` with this:

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
      - assets/
```

My folders are summarized like this:

```
<project-folder>
 - pubspec.yaml
 - assets
   - images
     - d4.png
```

And I just replaced the base `_MyHomePageState` class from the base counter example like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
      body: Image(image: AssetImage('images/d4.png')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The image is not showing and I don't know why. If I replace the `AssetImage` with a `NetworkImage`, the image from the link works normally. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your asset folder in `pubspec.yaml` is wrong. Use one of the alternatives bellow:

1. Use this to import all of the images inside of the `images` directory

```dart
  assets:
      - assets/images/
```

2. Use this to import only the `d4.png` image file

```dart
  assets:
      - assets/images/d4.png
```

Then use the complete file path to access the image:

```dart
Image.asset('assets/images/d4.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `pubspec.yaml` add the following

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/d4.png
```

Then in your homepage

```
Image.asset('assets/images/d4.png')
```